# Can I exclude pages when exporting?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, export, data-driven-pages

Using ArcMap 10.2: when I'm exporting data-driven pages can I exclude single pages using some existing formatting rules (e.g. (-5) or [-5])? It would be a tad easier than my typical method of using ranges to exclude pages (e.g. 1-4, 6-10).

I realize I can set the definition query of the index layer to exclude the page to gain the same effect. I'm wondering if this type of option exists in the "Export" dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I"m aware of, one quick alternative would be:

1. Select Index layer features to exclude
2. In attribute table, switch selection of features
3. Use the Selected option for exporting pages

See image below:

[image]

You could add that idea here:

[ArcGIS Ideas](http://ideas.arcgis.com/)

Comment: Ok good answer. Didn't know I could use selected features due to the 'selection symbology' however I see the option to disable selection symbology so it should appear the same as if no selection has been made.